# AngularJS Filter: Return array of objects not matching expected string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

In AngularJS, the ['filter' filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) can look through an array of objects and return the array of only those with a string property value that contains a string comparator.

The following will thus give a list of every member of the array of objects `people` with any property like `surname: 'Smith'` or `occupation: 'Blacksmith'` or `address_1: '123 Smithfield Lane'` etc.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: 'Smith'">
        {{ person.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the best way to get an array of only the objects which *don't* contain the string `'Smith'` using AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

> The predicate to be used for selecting items from array.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> string: The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All   strings or objects with string properties in array that match this string will   be returned. This also applies to nested object properties. The predicate can be  negated by prefixing the string with !

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: '!Smith'">
    {{ person.name }}
</li>
```

If you want to filter by name only use an object predicate

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: { name : '!Smith'}">
    {{ person.name }}
</li>
```